# Non-Empty Unique Key Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How are unique keys generated in rails?

I have a spec that says `The backend will have a relational DB, with one table with the following schema: "user : string, password : string, count : int", with user enforced to be non-empty, a unique key.`

Does that mean if I use

```
rails generate scaffold UserModel user:string password:string count:int
```

A unique key will be generated for me? Will it have a non-empty requirement by default?

or would I need

```
rails generate scaffold UserModel user:string password:string count:int unique_key int
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly declare a unique key, the migration will create it automatically when you run it. Also why are you calling your User model - "UserModel"? You could just call it "User". So `rails g scaffold User user:string password:string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will generate the keys for you and will handle them internally. There is no need to explicitly include them.

So you can simply write something like:

```
rails generate scaffold User user:string password:string count:int
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails will automatically create an `id` field with the generator that is *unique* and *not null*. This should meet your requirements.